# How can I customize the html in Jquery daterangepicker plugin?

Tags: jquery, daterangepicker

The picture is the default daterangepicker. I want to add my own HTML (UI) into that instead of using the default one. For example, I want to change Today into a button base on my HTML code.

[image]

Comment: Create a button, trigger a click on today when clicking on that button.

Answer (score 0):

This is my Jquery Code

```
presetRanges: [{
        text: 'Today',
        dateStart: function() { return moment() },
        dateEnd: function() { return moment() }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can with a little CSS overwriting. For example, I changed the following:

```
 .ui-datepicker td {
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    padding: 0;
}

.ui-state-default,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-default,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-default {
    border: solid #FFF;
    border-width: 1px 0 0 1px;
}
```

And immediately got something a lot more similar to what you are wanting.